# how can I use for loop

Tags: php, for-loop

i just want ask how i can use for loop to print

```
123    
456
```

i'm try with this code:

```
<?php

    $a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

    foreach($a as $r){
        for($q = 0; $q < 3; $q++) {
            echo $r;
        }

        echo "<br />";

    }

?>
```

But the problem is, it prints:

```
111    
222    
333    
444    
555    
666
```

Comment: Just take the inner for loop away! This is basic php

Comment: `foreach (array_chunk($a, 3) as $chunk) { foreach($chunk as $nr) echo $nr; echo '<br />'; }`

Comment: @Rizier123 That will print each number on its own line.

Comment: @Ja͢ck It has a lack of research. The OP doesn't seem to understand how basic for loops work. Also, it's not really a useful question to the community.

Comment: Could you explain why you think your code would give your expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing the value of `$r` three times for each value of `$r`; what you want is to print each value and print a break after every third.

Something like this would work:

```
foreach ($a as $i => $r) {
    echo $r;
    // insert break after every third value
    if ($i > 0 && ($i + 1) % 3 == 0) {
        echo '<br />';
    }
}
```

Or, you could use `array_chunk()` to split the array up in chunks of three and print each of those.

```
foreach (array_chunk($a, 3) as $chunk) { 
    foreach ($chunk as $nr) {
        echo $nr;
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_chunk($a, 3)  and then use implode , that will give you required result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$result='';
$i = 1;
foreach($a as $r)
{
$result.=$r;
    if($i%3 == 0)
    {
        echo $result."<br />";
        $result='';
    }
  $i++;  
}
```